Docker Compose example of a Traefik local plugin
I'm trying to create a simplified example of a Traefik plugin in local mode (https://plugins.traefik.io/install), but am running into a field not found, node: myplugin error. Here is my docker-compose.yml:
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --experimental.localplugins.myplugin.modulename=github.com/khpeek/my-plugin
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./my-plugin:/plugins-local/src/github.com/khpeek/my-plugin

  whoami:
    image: traefik/whoami:latest
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.localhost`)
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.http.middlewares.my-plugin.myplugin
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.middlewares=my-plugin@docker
      - traefik.http.middlewares.whoami-auth.forwardauth.address=http://host.docker.internal:4181
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.middlewares=whoami-auth

where the directory structure is as follows:
.
├── docker-compose.yml
└── my-plugin
    ├── .traefik.yml
    ├── go.mod
    └── myplugin.go

and myplugin.go is a simple plugin that adds a foo header with the value bar:
package myplugin

import (
    "context"
    "net/http"
)

type Config struct{}

func CreateConfig() *Config {
    return &Config{}
}

type MyPlugin struct {
    next http.Handler
    name string
}

func New(_ context.Context, next http.Handler, _ *Config, name string) (http.Handler, error) {
    return &MyPlugin{
        next: next,
        name: name,
    }, nil
}

func (m *MyPlugin) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.Header.Add("foo", "bar")
    m.next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}

its module name from go.mod is the same as declared as the modulename in the Traefik configuration, github.com/khpeek/myplugin:
module github.com/khpeek/my-plugin

go 1.23.0

The .traefik.yaml file is simply adapted from an example:
# The name of your plugin as displayed in the Plugins Catalog web UI.
displayName: My Plugin

type: provider

# The import path of your plugin.
import: github.com/khpeek/my-plugin

# A brief description of what your plugin is doing.
summary: Adds a header

# Medias associated to the plugin (optional)
iconPath: foo/icon.png
bannerPath: foo/banner.png

# Configuration data for your plugin.
# This is mandatory,
# and Plugins Catalog will try to execute the plugin with the data you provide as part of its startup validity tests.
testData:
  Headers:
    Foo: Bar

When I try running this using docker compose up, I get a field not found error:
> docker compose up
[+] Running 2/0
 ✔ Container traefik-docker-compose-example-traefik-1  Created                                                                                  0.0s 
 ✔ Container traefik-docker-compose-example-whoami-1   Created                                                                                  0.0s 
Attaching to traefik-1, whoami-1
whoami-1   | 2024/09/03 15:51:39 Starting up on port 80
traefik-1  | 2024-09-03T15:51:39Z ERR error="field not found, node: myplugin" container=whoami-traefik-docker-compose-example-5d092b6fcc269917c46b28d319fec17966aeac7f3d51bb370c5593d47a64e3c9 providerName=docker

According to this README,

The "field not found" error occurs, when an unknown property is encountered in the dynamic or static configuration.


One way to check whether a configuration file is well-formed, is to validate it with:

JSON Schema of the static configuration
JSON Schema of the dynamic configuration


It wasn't immediately clear to me from the JSON schema for the static configuration what is wrong with this configuration, and it seems similar to the one in the docs:

(even though these docs seem to have a different module name in the description from the example). Any ideas how to make this work?

It turns out that the cause of the field not found error is this line in the whoami service's dynamic configuration:
      - traefik.http.middlewares.my-plugin.myplugin

It seems that this is not a field of MiddlewareInfo which embeds Middleware (https://github.com/traefik/traefik/blob/e8335a94a4868689e96f15f11b8bc6fae66ddbce/pkg/config/dynamic/middlewares.go#L14-L48).
That said, I haven't been able to confirm that the plugin is working as expected (I added a log line the ServeHTTP handler and don't see it being called in the Docker Compose logs), so any suggestions welcome.

I've been using your example and got it working by doing the following:
docker-compose.yml, change modulename to moduleName.
- --experimental.localplugins.myplugin.moduleName=github.com/khpeek/my-plugin

dynamic configuration whoami service labels, where you call your plugin, it needs to be the configuration for said plugin:
# old
- traefik.http.middlewares.my-plugin.myplugin
# new
- "traefik.http.middlewares.my-plugin.plugin.myplugin.Headers.Foo=bar"

I believe the error field not found, node: myplugin relates to dynamic configuration missing for the plugin, as mentioned in other posts: https://community.traefik.io/t/field-not-found-node-address/15420

I'm not sure what other problems will exist in your configuration, but as a first step I'd try mapping your plugin directory to the location specified in the documentation you linked to (https://plugins.traefik.io/install). From the "Local Mode" section:

The plugins must be placed in ./plugins-local directory, which should be in the working directory of the process running the Traefik binary.

Since the docker container uses its root user to run traefik, try changing your my-plugin directory mapping to this:
    volumes:
      - ./my-plugin:/root/plugins-local/src/github.com/khpeek/my-plugin

UPDATE: I know that my answer here is wrong. Sorry for misleading you. I tried to correct it on the day I posted it, but no longer had enough rep points after the down-vote. My was mistake misreading the traefik docs and thinking that they were referencing the home directory of the user that started the traefik process rather than the working directory of the process, and those obviously don't have to be the same (and are not in this case).

Your comment says that the Docker container uses the root user to run Traefik, but the suggested code change suggests that the directory running the Traefik binary is the /root directory. As far as I can tell, the Traefik image is based on alpine:3.20 (https://github.com/traefik/traefik/blob/e8335a94a4868689e96f15f11b8bc6fae66ddbce/Dockerfile#L2) and the root directory there is just / (which I determined using docker run --rm -it alpine:3.20 /bin/ash and using the pwd command). How did you determine it should be the /root directory?

(I tried changing the directory to /root as you suggested but this leads to another error, raefik-1  | 2024-09-03T18:40:37Z ERR Plugins are disabled because an error has occurred. error="1 error occurred:\n\t* failed to open the plugin manifest plugins-local/src/github.com/khpeek/my-plugin/.traefik.yml: open plugins-local/src/github.com/khpeek/my-plugin/.traefik.yml: no such file or directory\n\n" plugins=["myplugin"], as I suspected base on my comment above).

You're getting the new error because my suggestion worked. But as I said in my answer, I think it's likely you also have other configuration issues. I just wanted to help you get past the first one in which your plugin wasn't recognized at all.
Your next issue is that you don't have a plugin manifest file. I would go take a closer look at the directory structure in the documentation and follow that exactly.

@KurtPeek, specifically, your second issue is that you don't have a .traefik.yml file at the root of your plugin's directory describing it. See https://plugins.traefik.io/create.
I'll add that it's poor form to down-vote the only help you've had so far, especially since I was correct. Your follow-up issues should technically be new questions.

I forgot to include it in my initial problem post (from which I got the directory structure using tree . which doesn't show hidden files) but I actually do have a .traefik.yml file which I've now added to the description (and updated the directory structure to be the one returned by tree -a . including hidden files). I maintain that your answer is incorrect because with the .traefik.yml file, I get the error with your suggested path and no error with the path as in the description.

@KurtPeek, I want to acknowledge that I was wrong. My mistake was initially misreading the traefik docs and thinking that they were referencing the home directory of the user that started the traefik process rather than the working directory of the process, and those obviously don't have to be the same (and are not in this case). I tried to acknowledge my error on the day we were having this back and forth, but your down-vote took my rep score below 10 and I wasn't able to reply.
